# how to have mvc view jquery click function call partial view jquery and return values?

Tags: jquery, partial-views

I created a partial view to make a set of controls reusable(like a user control in web forms) i want to be able to call a jquery function from the parent view to get values from controls within partial view. not sure if this is possible or not i have tried trigger with no luck and also triggerhandler but couldn't get a value to return.

here is an exaple of what im going for

--view--

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
  var Adddata = $(document).triggerHandler("addfunc");
  var txt1 = adddata.txt1val;
});
```

--end view--

--partial view--

```
$(document).bind('addfunc', function () {
   Adddata = {};
   Adddata.txt1val = $("#txt1").val();  
   return Adddata;
});
```

--end partial view--

Comment: Can you please provide some more explanation that what you are trying to approach. Please provide the code in your post

Comment: im trying to make a set of controls reusable by putting them in a partial view. i need the parent view to call the jquery function in the partial view and return data to the parent view. this way i can use these controls on multiple views, similar to a user-control in web forms.

Comment: you can directly call the function this case as there is no event required for the partial view to load